# How to store and handle a big wordlist?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have I .txt file with 200k+ words in it. I will use this file to check if a specific word exists or not. What would be the best way to store this so that I can read it fast, I will not change the content of the file just read from it.

I'm guessing its not so good to have it in a .txt file and then save it to some sort of array. I've heard something about database is that the way to go here?
I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @H2CO3 Do you think that would be good approach in this particular case?

Comment: I'd split the file up into smaller files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried loading it into memory? It might not be that bad. By loading it into memory I mean putting it inside an `NSArray` like you suggested already.

The other way to go could be a database. SQLite is the way to go on iOS. (or Core Data but that is a bit overkill for your problem) I am not going to explain how to use SQLite because there are lots of tutorials to find on the internet :)

Comment: No I haven't tried yet, I just wanted to know the alternatives before I do something stupid. So you think I might be good to load 200000 words in to an array? I have never used such a big array, wouldn't it take long time to loop through it every time I need to check a word?

Comment: Then SQLite is a safe bet. It has indexes to quickly search through your list of words.